# Given an executable file, display its complete path

Tags: c, linux

Given an executable file, its complete path sholud be displayed in linux (using C).
The executable file can be in current directory or it can be in some other directory.

It should be similar to TYPE command in unix. e.g. with `type cp`,  the result should be `/bin/cp`.

Can any one provide me the code please?
Atlest a system call related to it.

Comment: It's more like "*Do you haz teh codez?*"

Comment: There is no system call for it.

Comment: What if you have two executable files with the same name (and possibly the same behaviour) in two different directories? (I have a bunch of "a.out" executables spread through my hard disk)

Comment: The question is about standard executables which we use on terminal. like cp, ls etc.. Not a local executables.

Answer (score 2):

This is very simple. I don't want to give you any code but the basic idea.

- iterate all the paths in $PATH environment variable.
- for each path check if the executable you are looking for exists.

  - if exist echo the current path.

Here is a project [findcom](https://github.com/shiplu/findcom) I wrote long ago for windows operating system with .net 2.0 that searches for commands. You might get some idea from the source.

Answer (score 1):

To get the full path to the executable that will run when you type a command, use which

```
$ which bash
/bin/bash
```

To search all of your paths (including MANPATH) use whereis

```
$ whereis bash
bash: /bin/bash /etc/bash.bashrc /usr/share/man/man1/bash.1.gz
```

The whereis can be helpful if you have executables with the same name in different parts of your path, like sysV shutdown (/usr/sbin/shutdown) and berkeley shutdown (/usr/ucb/shutdown) on Solaris systems. `which` tells you which one you'll run by default, and `whereis` gives you all the possibilities.

If you don't get a response back, that means it's a shell builtin and not an executable,

```
$ which while
$ whereis while
while:
```

however, if it exists as a shell builtin AND an executable, it will return the path to the executable, but will run the builtin unless the path to the executable is specified.

```
$ which test
/usr/bin/test
$ whereis test
test: /usr/bin/test /usr/share/man/man1/test.1.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

Linux uses $PATH environment variable to find the executable program. You usually don't give full path to execute the program (i.e. you just execute ls, not /usr/bin/ls). The executable name is searched under the directories under $PATH. The $PATH environment variable looks something like:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin
```

System will find the executable file under the :-separated directories. What you have to do is separate this string wrt ":" and then concatenate the program name to the end; issue a stat call. If the stat returns successfully that means the program is there. If not go to the next candidate. System, like you'll do, will execute the first-found path.